# Indexes on Slave

Tags: mysql, replication

I already have a my system with Master-Slave replication.

I have started using Slave for data fetching. So, I need to create some extra indexes on Slave.[Not In master - however be informed that the Master already has indexes].

I already read some posts but couldn't clear my doubts. They say If you create primary key-foreign key-unique index on slave then there could be an issue. however I'm not going to go for any of these constraints on slave.

I simply want to create non-clustered/secondary indexs on slave. would I face any issues if I do so ?

Thank you.

Comment: Adding a `FOREIGN KEY` on the Slave only _could_ lead to a violation that was not caught on the Master.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create secondary indexes on slave whenever required. There is no issue in creating secondary indexes **`(Non Primary and Non Unique)`**.

If you create `Primary` and `Unique` on slave there will be chances that your replication will fail with `duplicate key error` on slave.

Take a example I have a table `testRepl` on master without having any index on it and has following structure and data

```
show create table testRepl\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: testRepl
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `testRepl` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` char(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM testRepl;
+------+-------+
| id   | name  |
+------+-------+
|    1 | Abdul |
|    2 | Jai   |
+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Initially we will have same table structure and data on slave as well , but assume you created a **`Primary key Index`** on **`id`** column on slave, and someone inserted id value as 2 on master on master the insertion would be successful but it will fail on slave as value 2 already exists there and the column is primary key indexed. So the insertion will fail and replication will break.

Comment: thats right, and Understood, So, this would be only issue right ???? I'm certainly not going to create primary or unique index on slave. I just want to create multiple column secondary indexes that's it. it won't have any issues right ??

Comment: Yes correct on slave you can create your indexes